# Binding properties of inherited classes

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I got three models. How can I bind the property of my subclass?

ViewModel Object_A:

```
private Object_A _object_A;
public Object_A Object_A
{
    get => _object_A;
    set => SetValue(ref _object_A, value);
}
```

Object_A class:

```
public class Object_A : BaseViewModel
{
    private Object_B _object_B;
    public Object_B Object_B
    {
        get => _object_B;
        set => SetValue(ref _object_B, value);
    }
}
```

Object_B class:

```
public class Object_B  : BaseViewModel
{
    private string _id = string.Empty;

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id
    {
        get => _id;
        set => SetValue(ref _id, value);
    }
}
```

How can I access the property `Object_A.Object_B.Id` in `XAML`?

I tried `Text="{Binding Object_A, Path=Object_B.Id}"` so far...

Comment: As extra info, you've got the path and binding mixed up. The path tells it where to look for the binding property relative to the BindingContext. So here you tell it to go to `Object_B` on the BindingContext, then on that `Object_B` go to `Id` and there it'll try to look for the property `Object_A` to bind to (but `Id` doesn't have a property `Object_A` so it fails). If you wanted to `Text="{Binding Id, Path=Object_A.Object_B}"` should also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your `BindingContext` is `ViewModel`, then this should work

```
Text="{Binding Object_A.Object_B.Id}"
```

Comment: It doesn’t. That’s what I thought too.

Comment: I'd verify that just Object_A works, then Object_A.Object_B, etc - to see where it starts breaking down

Comment: Good advice. I’ll try it.

Comment: @paulvoelker how did you finally fix this?

Comment: It was kind of a real noob mistake of mine. I had to instance all the subclasses in their parent classes and then it worked just as you and I expected.